# Vimでコピーする時にみなさんどうしてますか？

Tags: vim

Vimで開いたファイル (例えばMarkdownファイル) の内容をコピーして、GitHubなどのWikiにペーストしたいとします。

'ctrl + c'ではコピーされずインサートモードから抜けてしまうので利用できません。

yなどでコピーすることはできますが、webサイトに貼り付けるのはレジスタが使えないためpで貼り付けることはできません。

このような場合みなさんはどうするのでしょうか？

私はmdファイルをメモ帳などで開いて(vimが使えないエディタを開いて)ctrl + cでコピーしていますが、二度手間なので良い方法が知りたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらのリンクは参考にならないでしょうか。
[vimエディタからクリップボードを利用する。](https://nanasi.jp/articles/howto/editing/clipboard.html) 
私は「*レジスタ」をよく使っています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。クリップボードにもコピーできるのですね。いままでの作業が楽になるのでとても助かります。